# Spinner onItemSelected's previous position overrides current position inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have 2 fragments:
1. A fragment containing a `List` of items.
2. A fragment containing a `spinner` of the same items.

I have to click the list item to go the spinner fragment(sending position from list fragment and then `setselection()` on spinnerfragment )

For the first time when I click the list item and go to the spinner fragment , the selected item is selected in spinner without any problem,which will then do some functions.
Then I go to the same list fragment via nav drawer and click a different item,what happens is the `onItemSelected` gets fired three times (checking in debug mode) .The previous position is overrides the current position, i.e the `setSelection` of the current item is not invoking immediately and the previous spinner position is used to display the previous spinner item.

I don't know what is the source of `onItemSelected` being fired 3 times.Thanks

This is where the list item click occurs and I set the id to be selected:

```
holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IncidentFragment incidentFragment = fragmentInteractionListener.getIncidentFragment();
            fragmentInteractionListener.setGroupId(groupStatistics.get(position).getId());
            ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, incidentFragment).commit();              
        }
    });
```

This is the spinner side(IncidentFragment) and problem occurs onItemSelected:

```
mGroupId = mListener.getGroupId();
ArrayAdapter<String> groupsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, groups);
        groupSpinner.setAdapter(groupsAdapter);
        groupSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        for (int position = 0; position < mGroupList.size(); position++) {
            if (mGroupId == mGroupList.get(position).getGroupId())
            {
                groupSpinner.setSelection(position);// first time item click from 1st fragment works,but this position is not sent for the next time 
                break;
            }
        }
        groupSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {         
                    mGroupId = mGroupList.get(i).getGroupId();
                    mListener.setGroupId(mGroupId);
                    //the problem occurs here, first selected position from first fragment or the spinner selected item always overrides the position from seteSelection()
                    //Only works for the first time since no spinner selections have been made at that time
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
```

This is oNavigationItemSelected from Navigation Drawer to access back that
list:

```
case R.id.dashboard:
              drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
              getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, dashboardEngineer).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Although I am able to select spinner items properly, the only concern is I am not able to set the value that is being used in setSelection() after one time.Thanks

Comment: can you add your code of first fragment?

Comment: Post code it will help to get problem faster.

Comment: For the time being, I have used a workaround, I detach and attach the fragment in the list item click, so that everytime the fragment is initalised and new spinner position is fed. If there is an existing spinner position, then it ignores setSelection().